# Is it possible to simulate Silverlight UI thread (to reproduce deadlock scenario)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, deadlock, ui-thread, simulate

I have a library with legacy code that causes a deadlock in a Silverlight application. What makes it harder to investigate is that it's only Silverlight app that fails. When used in WPF or Windows Store application, the same code runs fine (this a portable class library, so it can be used in different platforms).

Silverlight debugging is much slower and time-consuming than debugging desktop applications or unit tests. So I wonder if there's a technique to simulate Silverlight threading environment without SL runtime, so it will be possible to reproduce concurrency issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is not like the windows phone which has an emulator or a live connection. SL as you know is the live connection; hence there is no emulator. Since this occurs as a deadlock and only on one system, the SL system, then the code interaction of the portable library with SL *is the problem*.

It would be best to further isolate (buffer) any interactions with the UI from the library to lesson any deadlock situations.

Comment: When I ask about simulation in the context of SL, I only mean simulating (or mocking) its threading model in order to reproduce code deadlocks. I was hoping to be able to write a test where the code deadlocked in the same manner.